# Template specialization for rvalue reference method templates

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, specialization

I have a template function in `.hpp` file:

```
class Wrapper {
 public:
     ...
     template <typename T>
     void PutIntoStream(T &&input);
};
void Wrapper::PutIntoStream(T &&input) {/*implementation*/}
```

In my `.cpp` file this function is specialized:

```
template<>
void Wrapper::PutIntoStream(const int &input)
{}

template<>
void Wrapper::PutIntoStream(const std::string &input)
{}
```

But then I'm trying to run specializations the template function is run:

```
int val{0};
std::string s{"Val"};

PutIntoStream(val); // template <typename T> void PutIntoStream(T &&input)
PutIntoStream(s);   // is called in both cases
```

Can anyone tell me what's the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Nobody outside of your `.cpp` file knows anything about the specializations in the `.cpp` files. Did you try explicitly declaring a specialization in the header file?

Comment: Perhaps there's some confusion between _template instantiation_ (which can be in a cpp file) and _template specialization_ (which must be visible to code that's expected to use it)

Comment: Unrelated to the issue but rather to the title of your question : no function here is specialized to handle specifically rvalue references. Your first specialization (T&&) is a universal reference (or forwarding reference). More info https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

Comment: because templates can only be implemented in the header unless you follow some special means which you you do not, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: After an hour with no feedback, I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)